# How to add the fetched file time to the text column?

Tags: linux, shell, curl

This is a text that stores the download address and it looks like this.

```
http://speedtest.newark.linode.com/100MB-newark.bin
http://speedtest.dallas.linode.com/100MB-dallas.bin
http://speedtest.london.linode.com/100MB-london.bin
http://speedtest.tokyo2.linode.com/100MB-tokyo2.bin
```

I would like to get the modification time of the download link and add it to the front of the download address.

This is the expected result.

```
2020-11-22 22:01:38 http://speedtest.newark.linode.com/100MB-newark.bin
2020-08-09 14:18:58 http://speedtest.dallas.linode.com/100MB-dallas.bin
2020-11-22 16:25:05 http://speedtest.london.linode.com/100MB-london.bin
2020-08-09 00:26:50 http://speedtest.tokyo2.linode.com/100MB-tokyo2.bin
```

I know I can get the file time through the `http header`, which is the query command.

```
curl -sLI link | grep -i '^Last-Modified' | cut -c16- | date -f- '+%Y-%m-%d %T'
```

So the question is, how do I add the query results to the file column?

Any help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first get all links' Last-Modified timestamp to a file then `paste` them together doing as following:

```
<links.txt xargs -L -n1 -I{} curl -sLI {} |grep -i '^Last-Modified' |cut -c16- |date -f- '+%Y-%m-%d %T' >last.modifiedOutput
paste -d' ' last.modifedOutput links.txt
```

Comment: If the file time query fails due to network problems, can a preset value be returned? For example, return the current system time.

Comment: @Matthew do `<links.txt xargs -L -n1 -I{} curl -sLI {} |grep -i '^Last-Modified' |cut -c16- |date -f- '+%F %T' || date '+%F %T'`

Comment: It seems that it does not work as expected, it does not return the current system time when querying for a link that does not exist. `<links.txt xargs -l -n1 -I{} curl -sLI {} |grep -i '^Last-Modified' |cut -c16- |date -f- '+%F %T' || date '+%F %T'`

Comment: @Matthew maybe add `--fail` to the curl options too?